# MATLAB won't give out the answer

Tags: matlab, primes

I wrote my own function in MATLAB which will returns me a "true" if the input number is a prime number and a "false" if it isn't.

With the numbers 0, 1, and 2 it's working, but with anything above 2 it's not doing anything. (BTW, I recreated isprime, so obv I won't use that here.)

```
function [A] = myprime(p)
    m = 2;

    if p<1
        disp('Number too low')
    end

    if p == 1
        A = false;
    end

    if p == 2
        A=true;
    end

    if p < 2
        while m < p
            A = true;
            x = mod(p, m);
            if x == 0
                m=p;
                R=false;
            end
            m=m+1;
        end
    end
end
```

As you can see, it gives results for 0,1 and 2, but nothing for any number above 2:

[image]

Comment: With no knowledge of matlab specifically, it's pretty apparentl you have no code to handle any cases where `p > 2`. Looks like a typeo on your last `if` possibly. Can't say beyond that.

Comment: Not only that, there is also no code that sets `A=false;` in any case. So even with the typo removed, all input numbers are returned to be prime. I suppose `R=false;` is another typo and should be `A=false;`.

Answer (score 0):

there is a problem with your code, you don't declare the state where p>2 and also I think the line that you declared

```
if p<2
while m<p
```

is not true because you set m=2 and that state won't happen.